# 2008 4.6L mustang

Tags: ford, sparkplugs, mustang

I have been looking for spark plugs for the old H code engine. It is a fine thread and used a 5/8 socket. Its a 2008 ford gt mustang.  Any ideas of what soark plug would work? Thank you in advance

Comment: Check out catalogues by NGK or Champion or Bosch.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I've found to find parts for any car is to use [RockAuto.com](https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/ford,2008,mustang,4.6l+v8,1441221,ignition,spark+plug,7212) (no affiliation). Go to the site, drill down to your vehicle, then find the parts. Not that you need to buy from them, as I still search other sources. However, their parts indicators are usually spot on and give you exactly what you're looking for. Use their part numbers and brands, then do a search for those specific parts to find the best prices, or go down to your local parts store and buy them their. This works well here in the States, though I don't know a good source for parts searches in other parts of the world.